# BigCommerce Orders API: unable to update

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to update an existing order in the store using PUT requests to the V2 orders API:

> https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{$$.env.store_hash}/v2/orders/{id}

According to the [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/orders/putordersid), I should be able to update the following:

> customer_id, status_id, Add a new product, Add a custom product, billing_address

The only thing I have success changing is the status_id. I can use the example body provided at the bottom of the documentation page:

```
{
  "status_id": 1,
  "billing_address": {
    "first_name": "Trisha",
    "last_name": "McLaughlin",
    "company": "",
    "street_1": "123 Main Street",
    "street_2": "",
    "city": "Anywhere",
    "state": "Some State",
    "zip": "12345",
    "country": "United States",
    "country_iso2": "US",
    "phone": "",
    "email": "elsie@example.com"
  }
}
```

I get a 200 OK response with no body. But in the store only the status changes. If I intentionally misspell a field, then I get an error response, which suggests to me that the body is correctly formatted, but ignored.

Can anyone provide an example of a body that updates billing address or adds a new product which the API will act on?

I'm generating the PUT requests with Postman currently, but will move to PHP later.

Thanks.

Edit:

This is an example of a request I tried for adding an existing product, also accepted but doesn't work.

```
{
    "products": [{
        "product_id": 111,
        "quantity": 5
    }]
}
```

Edit 2: To provide more context, the orders I'm trying to update already have existing products and have been 'paid for' (the products are free). I've tried adding products that are already in the order as well as new ones. I've tried this on orders with various status as well. Also, the orders are processed by guest accounts, so the customer_id field is 0. I have not tried doing this with a registered account order. Could any of these things be causing the issue?

Edit 3: For anyone else wandering by, this appears to be a bug that is associated with downloadable products. Please see the comment chain under the accepted answer for details.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a request body?

Comment: @T.J. I'm using the one they provided as example, which is quoted in the question.

Comment: Using the example above and changing the product_id to one that is in the store, it does return a 200. Then doing a query against the products sub resource(https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-products/getordersorderidproducts), I can see that it was added to the order.

Comment: @T.J. Sorry, this isn't working at all for me. Are you including anything else in the body? I'm using V2 API with raw application/json body. Headers are the client, token, content-type and accept. I'm checking in the store as well as querying the {order_id}/products API, and neither reflects any change. Is this an issue with Postman? I can try making the request in PHP and see if that works.

Comment: After testing it looks like we need to update how to add a new product to the order. The structure was incorrect in the examples. I was not able to reproduce the other issues you are having, I listed the example body for each PUT below that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new product:

```
{
    "products": [{
        "name": "Poster",
        "quantity": 5,
        "price_inc_tax": 12.45,
        "price_ex_tax": 10.12
    }]
}
```

Add an existing product: Make sure to update the product_id to one that is in the store.

```
{
    "products": [{
        "product_id": 187,
        "quantity": 5,
        "price_inc_tax": 12.45,
        "price_ex_tax": 10.12
    }]
}
```

It will return a 200. Then query the [Order Products](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/order-products/getordersorderidproducts) to see a list of products on the order.

To update a billing address this structure works:

```
{
"billing_address": {
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "street_1": "455 Main Street",
    "street_2": "",
    "city": "Austin",
    "state": "Texas",
    "zip": "78751",
    "country": "United States",
    "country_iso2": "US",
    "phone": "",
    "email": "rick@sanchez.com"
}
}
```

Customer id needs to match a customer id that exists in the store. To get a list of customers use the [customers endpoint](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/customer-subscribers/customers-api/customers/getcustomers).

```
{
    "customer_id": 20
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid this is still not working for me. To provide more context, the orders I'm trying to update already have existing products and have been 'paid for' (the products are free). I've tried adding products that are already in the order as well as new ones. I've tried this on orders with various status as well. Also, the orders are processed by guest accounts, so the customer_id field is 0. I have not tried doing this with a registered account order. Could any of these things be causing the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to add products that have $0 amount? Please provide your code, not the documentation example code. 

You can only update a customer that exists. Which means they have a customer id in the store. Trying to add an id that does not exist will not work.

Comment: I tested a guest order or customer_id of 0 and adding products with $0. Both worked for me.
What are the products returned if you run this query:
`https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{$$.env.store_hash}/v2/orders/{order_id}/products`

Comment: I'm not using any original code, only the JSONs provided as example as well as the ones you gave. The only modification was changing product_id to 111, which corresponds to a sample product that exists by default in a new store (priced at $25). I've also tried product_id corresponding to free digital items I've created with no success.

By billing address update, I mean changing the billing address listed on the order, not in a customer account (there is no customer account as it's a guest checkout). I can, however, successfully change the customer_id associated with the order.

Comment: This is the response I get: https://imgur.com/a/94EkwGs

That's an item that was originally in the order added through the storefront checkout process.

Comment: Also, I'm using a trial store, is that potentially an issue? The API account I'm using has every permission set to modify.

Comment: Using a trial store isn't an issue. I haven't been able to replicate the issue. You can try creating a new order via api, then adding an existing product and a new product to that

Comment: I just created a new order based on the example here: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/orders/orders-api/orders/postorders

With product_ids changed to match what I have in store, and one of the product options removed. The order was created successfully - I can see it both in the store as well as via GET API. I then tried to add a custom product based on your first example, but that yielded no response as before.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing differently. Since this is a trial store, I have no qualms with providing the API account I'm using:

Store hash: kuke4t1bai
Client ID: 6okp2nbufggr7a6agcpambg1p73pnqw
Client secret: h52j20r90zylrsq6ljcpxj93zn5nprz
Client token: r5sbdplsl28ssrkl8axd1vhgaxzcx6i

Please feel free to test with those credentials to see if you can reproduce my issue.

I'll try starting a new store with a new API account if I still can't figure out what's wrong. This is very baffling.

Comment: when you say no response can you clarify that? As in you get a 200 and when you check the order products resource its not added or is there a different error.

Comment: I get a 200 response with no body following the PUT request (as opposed some other successful POST requests where a JSON formatted body is returned).

I can then access the order itself as well as the product resource with GET as usual with no errors. It's just that no changes have been made to either aside from potentially status_id and customer_id if those changes were requested.

Comment: Keep trying for now. I am going to check with a few people on my end to see what is happening. We did get the documentation updated with a working example, we just need to figure out why this is not working for you.

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much for all the help. I'm going to start a new store and see if the problem persists. If you will provide an avenue, I'd be more than happy to leave a positive review on BigCommerce in regards to the support (I'm presuming you're an employee).

Comment: Hello, I just tried the same exact thing on a new store this morning and everything worked. I went back and checked my old API account and found that it was missing the following scopes: Channel Listings, Channel Settings, Sites & Routes, Content. Sorry for the misinformation earlier - I could have sworn I ticked all the modify boxes when making it, but I guess it was one of these permissions that was missing (though none of those strike me as relevant here). Strange that I could modify parts of the order but not others.

Anyways, thanks again for the help.

Comment: I went back to the first store and tried to make the same PUT requests on a new full-scope API account. The original problem still persists. At this point I think the problem is associated with the account. Possibly a bug with BC?

Comment: Sorry for the spam. I figured out what's wrong. 

The non-responsive issue I described occurs if the order includes a downloadable product at the time of order creation. Orders whose products are later reclassified as physical are still unresponsive.

Additionally, IDs associated with downloadable products can not be added to any order regardless.

I believe this is a bug with BigCommerce.

Comment: Awesome! If you have a second, can you reply to Sam below. we are looking into what is going on.

Comment: No problem. Where can I see Sam's comments?

Comment: We did figure out based on your testing and feedback that an order that has a digital or downloadable product can only update the `customer_id` and the `status_id`. We opened a bug ticket on our end. The current workaround we found is to create another order or have the digital and physical items split. The documentation will get updated in the meantime. You can also fill out the feedback form on developer.bigcommerce.com so we can update you on the tickets progress.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/b3A6MzU5MDQ3MzE-update-an-order

it states:

"The status will include one of the (string, options) - values defined under Order Statuses. This value is read-only. Do not attempt to modify or set this value in a POST or PUT operation."

It appears you cannot update the order status from the api...